# Joining on "greater than" returning more than one row for left table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have a query.

```
SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN ranks ON ranks.minPosts <= users.postCount
```

This returns a row every time it is matched. By using a `GROUP BY users.id` I get each row as a individual id.

However, when they group I only get the first row. I would instead like the row with the highest value of `ranks.minPosts`

Is there a way to do this, also, would it be faster (less resources) to just use two different queries?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there is only one column in `ranks` that you want, you can do this using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT u.*,
       (select r.minPosts
        from ranks r
        where r.minPosts <= u.PostCount
        order by minPosts desc
        limit 1
       ) as minPosts
FROM users u;
```

If you need the entire row from `ranks`, then join it back in:

```
SELECT ur.*, r.*
FROM (SELECT u.*,
             (select r.minPosts
              from ranks r
              where r.minPosts <= u.PostCount
              order by minPosts desc
              limit 1
             ) as minPosts
      FROM users u
     ) ur join
     ranks r
     on ur.minPosts = r.minPosts;
```

(The `*` is for convenience; you should list out the columns you want.)

Answer (score 2):

Because you're using mysql, this will work:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, users.id user_id
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN ranks ON ranks.minPosts <= users.postCount
    ORDER BY ranks.minPosts DESC
) x
GROUP BY user_id
```

Mysql always returns the *first* row encountered for each unique group, so if you first *order* the data, *then* use the non-standard grouping behaviour, you'll get the row you want.

#### Disclaimer:

Although this works reliably in practice, the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html) says *not* to rely on it. If you use this convenient approach (which will reliably pass any test you can write), you should consider that it is not recommended by mysql and that later releases of mysql may not continue behave in this way.

Comment: There can be an issue with this query.. Just so the op knows if there is a duplicate column name in both tables this will throw an error you should specify the column names in the sub query

Comment: @JohnRuddell good point - it would have exploded. I think that's fixed it. Although we don't have the schema, so it's hard to be sure

Comment: Well `users.id, *` is incorrect syntax lol.. I would just put in "your_columns_here" and add a note at the bottom to specify the columns.. But yes without the schema its hard to know what to select :) +1 from me

Comment: Is it documented that MySQL will pick the first row from each group which shares the same `user_id`? I thought the server could pick any value from the non-aggregated columns.

Comment: @unutbu I know the doc says that, but in reality it's always the *first* row found

Comment: But then again you will still have the same error because you're pulling out all columns in both tables with the `*` and then you pull out that ID a second time and give it an alias... I would still recommend you keep it generic an just put in something like your column's here... And then just put a note at the end of the answer explaining that the op needs to put in the specific columns he wants to pull from the table

Comment: This answer uses an extension to `group by` that MySQL explicit warns against using:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes, so you've said many times before, to which I have always said - it works 100% of the time. If you want to be safe, whenever you upgrade mysql (which is rare), test this assertion. So far, every single release has behaved predicably as I have used it

Comment: @Bohemian: try this: `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'`, then try running the query. Expected result: Error 1055, Error 1140, or some such. (Works 100% of the time that sql_mode doesn't include ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY or ANSI.)  "Since you're using MySQL and current setting of sql_mode doesn't include ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY..."

Comment: @spencer7593 that's not the issue. we all know it's non-standard grouping behaviour. the question is if it's "safe" to rely on it. the doc says don't rely. I say as a matter of practicality, you can (and I do)

Comment: @Bohemian: The issue (as I see it) is that you've given "expert advice" with an example of code that is *not* guaranteed to work 100% of the time, an example which the documentation specifically *warns* against, and your answer gives NO indication that this behavior is a non-standard extension. Is it really true that "we *all* know that"? Are we 100% guaranteed that OP who asked the question, or future readers of this answer, *all* "know that"?

Comment: @spencer7593 I've included a reasonable disclaimer.

Comment: +1. @Bohemian: Nice. A disclaimer as short as the one that Gordon provided (with a link to the appropriate section of the MySQL Reference Manual) would suffice. "The example above relies on a MySQL-specific extension to GROUP BY (link to ref man). The documentation warns against relying on the behavior, " feel free to add the part about the query working, returning the right result set, the behavior we observe is *consistent*... I entirely agree with you that the query throwing an error is not really an issue... we'd rather the query return an error than return wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

What we'd really like to do would be to order the rows by `ranks.minPosts` before the group by. Unfortunately MySQL doesn't support that without using a subquery of some form.

If the ranks are already ordered by their ids then you can extract the id by selecting `MAX(ranks.id)`, and if they're not, you can still get the highest `ranks.minPosts` by selecting `MAX(ranks.minPosts)`. However, it would be nice to be able to get the entire record. I guess you're left with the subquery solution, which is as follows:

```
SELECT <fields> FROM users LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM ranks ORDER BY minPosts DESC) as r
    ON r.minPosts <= users.postCount GROUP BY users.id
```